# Autofac resolution error when no debugger attached

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, autofac

We are using Autofac to compose our application, and a Log4Net based logging mechanism. Following the Log4Net style, every object that requests `ILogger` in its constructor gets an instance of `Log4NetLogger` (our own wrapper class) that in turn gets the type of the requesting object passed into its constructor.

To do this with Autofac, we are using this (which I believe I found somewhere here on SO):

```
public class LoggingModule : Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry registry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += OnComponentPreparing;
    }

    private void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = e.Component.Activator.LimitType;
        e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(new[]
        {
            new ResolvedParameter((p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILogger), (p, i) => new Log4NetLogger(t))
        });
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<Log4NetLogger>().As<ILogger>();
    }
}
```

This works well - as long as the application is run from within Visual Studio with the debugger attached. If it is run on its own, it fails on the first attempt to resolve `ILogger`:

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Application.Infrastructure.Logging.Log4NetLogger' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Type type' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Type)'.
```

Replacing the above registration with this module fixes the error, but of course results in a loss of information about which class a log entry originates in:

```
public class SimpleLoggingModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterInstance(new Log4NetLogger(typeof(object))).As<ILogger>();
    }
}
```

The application registers many other types in the container (including auto-registration of a few whole assemblies), but everything else appears to work normally.

I have tried to reproduce the error in a small project with just the minimum necessary types, but the error does not occur there.

Does anyone have an idea about what might be the cause of this behavior? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the Load override and only going with the event handling.

There is an example of a log4net integration module on the Autofac wiki here:
https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Log4-Net-Integration

I'm guessing the problem is that when you're resolving something that needs your logger, Autofac is finding two possible parameters - the one you've manually supplied and the direct type registration.

Since it sounds like you can't do a direct resolution on the logger anyway (because it needs the type of the thing being resolved) the Load override is just confusing things and probably throwing a wrench in the works.

Comment: The explicit type registration was indeed the issue, but in a different way - I had not dug deep enough to find there was code directly resolving `ILogger` specifically when there is no debugger attached, which then led to the observed error about being unable to resolve a `Type` dependency. I have replaced the `RegisterType` call in `LoggingModule` with the `RegisterInstance` line from `SimpleLoggingModule`, and everybody is no able to get their loggers as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested a solution that works for me. There is a specific way to write your registrations that use ResolvedParameters

Replace the registration line:

```
builder.RegisterType<Log4NetLogger>().As<ILogger>();
```

With:

```
builder.RegisterType<Log4NetLogger>().As<ILogger>().
           WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == (typeof(Type)), (pi, c) => typeof(ILogger));
```

I tested this with some stub classes but at least the call `var logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();` returned an instance and did not throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks; that's not what I need, though. That always calls the constructor as `new Log4NetLogger(typeof(ILogger))`. I need the constructor called with the type of the object the logger is injected into - so, if the class that uses the logger is `ThingWithLogger`, the constructor call should be `new Log4NetLogger(typeof(ThingWithLogger))`. That's what my above code does, just not without the debugger attached.